# Open Public Documents folder in Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, wxwidgets

I have the following file I need to open in a windows explorer window

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\folder1\test.txt

So far opening this file using the above path is fine and I can read it as usual.

However when trying to open this this folder through Windows Explorer using `wxExecute((wxChar **)cmd, wxEXEC_ASYNC, NULL);` where cmd is the above path(minus the file), It opens to my user documents.

I've tried various Windows API functions to get the path, some including where Public Documents has it's own ID and these still generate the path I already have. Are there any CLI options I can give to Windows Explorer so that it can actually open Public Documents without reverting to my User Documents folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you cast your string to `wxChar**`? This just can't be right.

Second, you should be using [wxLaunchDefaultApplication()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.2/group__group__funcmacro__misc.html#ga04038d4c78e4c111d018b8f82b2d66c3) instead of "raw" `wxExecute()` in the first place (FWIW `wxLaunchDefaultApplication()` is a straightforward wrapper for `ShellExecute()` under MSW, while `wxExecute()` is much more complicated).

Comment: Casting was from a comment on similar question, was just trying different things.

wxLaunchDefaultApplication works. Not sure what about wxExecute gives it issues with the public folder structure but anything ShellExecute wise seems to be fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's undocumented, but has worked across multiple windows Versions since at least XP with the following command line:

```
explorer.exe /select,"path-to-open"
```

Note the comma, and make sure the path is quoted. The path may include a file name, in which case that file gets selected.

(With Windows 10, it's actually a good idea to use a file name, since otherwise the parent folder is opened with the specified sub folder selected)

Should be the same with `CreateProcess`, `ShellExecute`, or `system()`, or whatever comfort wxWidgets offer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually turned out to be an issue with wxExec from wxWidgets. Converting the command to a ShellExecute opened it up just fine. Potentially Widgets 2.9.5 can't handle Windows 10's pseudo folders and weirdness?.